# add css to a cell through client template in a kendo grid

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, client-templates

My cols are defind as belwo

```
x.Bound(y => y.IsStudentIn).Hidden(true);
x.Bound(y => y.Student).ClientTemplate("# if(IsStudentIn== false) {# <span style = \" background-color:red; \"></span>#}#");
```

if IsStudentIn = false, I want the Student cell to turn red color. Tried the above way, its not working.
How to add css to this specific td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer, I contacted telerik to get the answer

```
x.Bound(y => y.IsStudentIn).Hidden(true);
x.Bound(y => y.Student).ClientTemplate("# 
if(IsStudentIn== false) 
          {#"+ "<div style='background:red;'/>#:Student # </div>" + "# } 
                 else {#" + 
                        "#: Student #" + 
                     "# } #");
```